# Conference fee, travel costs and accommodation fees for Keynote Speaker and Technical Program Committees

Tags: conference, fees

I was invited to attend a conference as a keynote speaker and TPC panel. The sent message began:

> On behalf of the organizing committee, we are honored to invite you as a keynote speaker and the TPC Committee for [...]

This is the first time I have been invited as a keynote speaker or technical program committee. I would like to make sure that I will not be charged accommodation, travel or conference fees. Should I ask them via email? I also want to know if there is a reward or pocket money during the period of this conference in a professional manner. How?

Comment: Are you in a position where it would be appropriate to invite you to be a keynote speaker? Is the conference one you know that you and your colleagues would submit to and attend? If no to both, this is almost certainly a scam.

Comment: What's wrong with just asking them?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming this is a reputable conference, just ask whoever invited you straight up about the financial arrangements and how do you deal with them. There may be a stipend or not, but that is less likely than paying (all) expenses.

You will probably need to make your own arrangements and get reimbursed. There may be limitations, so don't expect first class travel or accommodations to be covered.

If it isn't reputable, then, well,...

Comment: How can I ask them about all fees in a professional manner?